# Dbeaber no logra conectarse a mi API de Node

Tags: mysql, nodejs, dbeaver

Tengo un archivo `.env` donde tengo los datos para la base de datos y mi archivo `config` donde las utilizo. En el `Dbeaber` agrego las credenciales de mi .env y al darle en probar conexión se queda cargando, no hace la conexión.

**.env**

```
# MYSQL
PORT = 4000
MYSQL_HOST = localhost
MYSQL_USER = root
MYSQL_PASSWORD = 
MYSQL_DB = gnk
```

**config**

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
    app: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 4000
    },
    mysql: {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST || 'localhost',
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'root',
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD || '',
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DB || 'example',
    }
}
```

Comment: Uno es _example_ y el otro es _gnk_, ¿realmente es correcto esto?

Comment: @padaleiana Era eso, el puerto y usar mysql2. Creía que tenia que poner el puerto 4000 en el Dbeaver pero hay que dejar el 3306 y aunque todo esté correcto es necesario usar el mysql2 para poder usar el caching_sha2_password.